# Concurrent programming in Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency, jvm, ghc

Two (related) questions about concurrent programming in Haskell compared to Java/Scala:

1. What do Haskeller's use for concurrent data structures? Is there anything analogous to Java's `java.util.concurrent.{ConcurrentHashMap, ConcurrentSkipListSet, ..}`. `MVar (Map k v)` does *not* count :). Shared mutable state is evil, but occasionally necessary.
2. Is there any equivalent to Java's `ExecutorService`? AFAIK, Haskell threads (see `fork#`, `yield#`, etc. in `GHC.Exts`) are all scheduled by something built into the RTS. But what if I specifically want to use a fork join pool, or schedule some computations on a thread pool? Being able to put `Future`'s on specific execution contexts is really handy in Scala, and I don't know how to do that in Haskell.

Comment: Why `MVar (Map k v)` does not count? What functionality do you miss from that?

Comment: 1 may be OT here since it's a library recommendation question. You can use `forkOn` to assign a thread to a particular capability. Maybe you could elaborate a little more on your second question? What kind of control do you need exactly? There are some packages on hackage that implement various work stealing schemes

Comment: @chi `MVar (Map k v)` prevents concurrent access altogether. Something like `ConcurrentHashMap` locks up only subsets of the map.

Comment: Re. 1) I found ctrie and stm-containers with a quick search

Comment: @jberryman I was sort of hoping there was something in the libraries that ship with GHC which would provide an abstraction layer over various work stealing schemes (as is the case in the Java standard library). Sounds like the answer to 2 is simply "not in any of the boot libs, but perhaps on Hackage".

Comment: @moonGoose I'm not sure I see why `stm-containers` need to have operations that live in the `STM` monad. I would expect concurrent data structures to have operations living in the `IO` monad and using `MVar` under the hood. As for `ctrie`, its API is quite lacking (I'd expect at least some `updateLookupWithKey`-like function). Also, it hasn't been updated since 2017.

Comment: This is a very broad question to attempt to answer on SO. I'd recommend reading Simon Marlow's free book, _[Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/)_

Comment: @Alec As I understand it, STM is just an useful abstraction for working in a concurrent context, offering better properties than eg. `MVar` (see package description http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm), so why wouldn't you want your structures' operations to live there? You can transfer `atomically :: STM a -> IO a`. You can also get the structure in `IO` if you want, see eg. `newIO :: IO (Map key value)`. Agreed re. `ctrie` but it's probably quite usable.

Answer (score 3):

An entire book could be written on this topic, so I'll try to touch on just the points you're asking about.

- You can use the `par` combinator to schedule *pure* computations to be done at some future point in time. The RTS *already* implements work-stealing queues for this and *already* maintains one thread per CPU core for running them. (If you link your program with the appropriate switches.) Note that this won't help one bit for impure code, and won't let you specify which thread or which core the code executes on.
- For shared *mutable* storage, you have two options.

  - Explicit locking using `MVar`. This has all the usual pitfalls of locking in other programming languages. (Deadlocks, forgetting to lock things, locking too many things, locking things too long, not locking them for long enough...) So `MVar (Map k v)` *absolutely* counts!
  - STM. You seem to misunderstand what this does. The whole *point* of STM is that you *don't need locks*. It lets you use shared mutable data structures "as if" they're not shared, but it automatically prevents data races, inconsistent state, and all the other usual problems with not using locks. It also allows a thread to wait on multiple conditions simultaneously. It's an incredible framework!
- If you want to run code on a specific OS thread, you're probably looking for `forkOS` rather than `forkIO`.

Given your use case, I suspect STM is probably what you're looking for. If you have a specific task you're trying to do, post another question and you will probably get more specific advise.

Comment: `par` is (unofficially?) deprecated in favor of `parEval` (or the more primitively implemented but inferior `rpar`) in `Control.Parallel.Strategies`. `par` has issues controlling speculative computation because there's no clear way to tell the system whether or not you still intend to use a result being calculated speculatively (I think there may be GC issues too). Marlow seems to think the whole built-in parallelism mechanism is a bit too hard to control. He prefers the `Par` monad these days.

Comment: There's one other mechanism for shared concurrent storage: atomic operations on `IORef` and various array types. These operations are good for writing lock-free structures, which are *sometimes* appropriate.